# Getting HTML response instead of Json response

Tags: java, json, httpurlconnection

I'm getting HTML response instead of JSON response. I'm using following code and I'm receiving HTML response as bf.readLine(). Is there any issue in following code or is this API issue?

```
String uri = "http://192.168.77.6/Ivr_ABN_API/?id=" + mobile;
    URL url;
    Gson json = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(uri);
        json = new Gson();

        HttpURLConnection connection;
        access_token = db.getAccessTokenFromDB();
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        System.out.println("URL:" + uri);

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        int status = connection.getResponseCode();
        resCode = Integer.toString(status);
        System.out.println("status is " + status);
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("inputStreamer " + in);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("bf.readLine() - " + bf.readLine());

        while ((output = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(output);
            System.out.println("output is " + output);
            resCode = obj.getString("resCode");
            resDesc = obj.getString("COUNT");

        }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps try sending the header Accept: application/json

If that doesn't work, then review the documentation for the API and see if there's something else you should be sending to return json.

Comment: Thank u very much. Adding "Accept: application/json" worked. :)

Comment: thank you for you answer, it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For `java`

Set The Request Property as the following:

```
con.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json")
```

It will solve the issue you are facing.

Comment: While this answer may be correct, it doesn't explain "Why" the code would solve the issue for a reader who might reach here later facing a similar problem. Please describe the answer clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stops here, often times receiving HTML as a response is due to `not calling a valid request method to your API in your fetch requests`